# Java Agregar funcines específicas a botones creados desde clase button interna

Tags: lista, javafx, botón

En JavaFx estoy programando un GridPanel dinámico de 3 filas por 2 columnas el cual lo lleno de botones por medio de una clase, ciclo for y los botones son almacendano en un ArrayList. A cada uno de los botones le he colocado un setOnAction(new EventHandler() y hasta ahí todo muy bien.

Lo que no se es como asignarle una función específica a cada EventHandler de cada botón creado y agregado al GridPanel.

Por ejemplo: 
al botón (0,0) asignar x método;
al botón (0,1) asignar x método;
y así sucesivamente.

No es viable agregar los métodos de forma manual o con switch ya que el usuario podrá agregar más botones.

```
class Botones {
    final Button boton;
    final String imgURL, price ;
    final ImageView imageView;
    String accion;

    //constructor
    public Botones(String imgURL_, String price_,String accion_) {
        this.imgURL = imgURL_;
        this.price = price_;
        this.accion = accion_;

        //se obtiene la ruta de la image o ícono
        Path imagePath = Paths.get(imgURL);
        File imageFile = imagePath.toFile();

        Image image = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString());
        this.imageView = new ImageView(image);

        this.boton = new Button(price);
        this.boton.setId(price);

        this.boton.setStyle(""
                + "-fx-content-display: TOP;"
                + " -fx-cursor: hand;"
                + "-fx-border-color: transparent;"
                + "-fx-text-fill: #333333;"
                + "-fx-font-size: 14px;"
                + "-fx-font-weight: bold;"
                + "-fx-background-position: 30%;");



        this.boton.setGraphic(imageView);
        this.boton.setMinHeight(165);
        this.boton.setMinWidth(234);

        this.boton.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle(Event event) {                        
                    System.out.println("Acción desde la clase botones " + accion_);

                }
            });

    }//del constructor



}//de la subclase que crea los botones
```

Con este método creo los botones y los almaceno en un List, para después ser agregars al GridPane (ListaBoton es un private ObservableList ListaBoton declarado al incio de la clase;
):

```
//creo los botones, los configura  y los almaceno en un List
private List<Botones> listaDeBotones ()
{
    ListaBoton = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < listaDatosDeBoton.size(); i++) {
        ListaBoton.add(new Botones(                    
                listaDatosDeBoton.get(i).getUrl(),//ruta de la imagen
                listaDatosDeBoton.get(i).getPrecio(), //nombre del boton
                listaDatosDeBoton.get(i).getComando()//accion del boton                    
        ));                                      
    }             

    return ListaBoton;
}
```

Comment: Si quieres que cada instancia de la clase tenga asociado un método diferente no te recomiendo usar setOnAction en el constructor. Aunque aquí no muestres el lugar en que está instancias los objetos realmente debería ser en ese punto donde les de un comportamiento distinto a cada uno.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir la parte del código en que creas los tres botones?

Comment: Con este método creo los botones y los almaceno en un List

Comment: Acabo de agregar el método donde creo y almaceno los botones en un List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como mencionaba, lo mejor sería no asignar un manejador de eventos
definido dentro de la propia clase, sino recibir uno por parámetro que pueda ser
definido externamente. La diferencia es que si defines el manejador en el
constructor este estará limitado a ser siempre el mismo.
Para aplicar lo dicho, haría falta cambiar la línea del constructor de esto:

```
public Botones(String imgURL_, String price_,String accion_)
```

A algo similar a esto:

```
public Botones(String imgURL_, String price_,String accion_, EventHandler manejador)
```

Y la llamada a setOnAction por su parte pasaría de esto:

```
this.boton.setOnAction(new EventHandler() { /* bla bla */  });
```

A esto:

```
this.boton.setOnAction(manejador);
```

De tal forma que ahora podrías definir las diferentes acciones que hará cada
botón externamente de la misma forma que lo haces con el resto de los datos.
Como no estoy seguro de como se genera "listaDatosDeBoton" voy a simplificar un
poco el ejemplo poniendo los datos en arreglos, de tal forma que por fuera
podrías hacer algo así:

```
private List<Botones> listaDeBotones() {
    listaBotones = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String[] urls = { "http://a.com", "http://b.com" };
    String[] precios = { "1.0", "2.0", "3.0" };
    String[] acciones = { "x", "y", "z" };
    EventHandler[] manejadores = {
        (event) -> { System.out.println("Evento del botón 1"); },
        (event) -> { System.out.println("Evento del botón 2"); },
        (event) -> { System.out.println("Evento del botón 3"); }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        listaBotones.add(new Botones(
                urls[i],
                precios[i],
                acciones[i],
                manejadores[i]
        ));
    }
}
```

Espero que no tengas conflicto con la notación () -> {}. Es simplemente una
expresión lambda que puede convertirse en una interfaz. Hacer esto:

```
(e) -> { System.out.println(e); }
```

Sustituye a:

```
new EventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event e) { System.out.println(e); }
}
```

Comment: Ok, haciendolo de la forma como lo indicas me he ahorrado varias lineas de código.

Comment: ¿Y la solución te sirvió entonces?